# can some one help me create a Power Automate flow

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

A power automate flow triggered on a daily schedule will check the list for any tickets that meet (or exceed) due date and submit a ticket to Orion via email. The last run and due date will then be updated. The system may be used to trigger tickets in supplier interface in the future - the destination system should be considered in the list schema.

i am having a hard time to develop a flow that executes the above requirement.

[image]

Comment: I guess we need more details about some the features you expect to work with. But for now, I can give you a bit of advice: **1)** draw a diagram of the flow so that when you create the flow you will know what to do. **2)** search for available endpoints (Web Services) or action in Power Automate to determine feasibility. **3)** create the flow and test it step by step.

Comment: **check the list for any tickets that meet (or exceed) due date**: where? in a database, in a file? in a SharePoint list? **Orion** : what is that?

Comment: orion is our ticketing system.

Comment: OK and what is the type of storage available for you (that supports CRUD operation via a Power Automate action) to store some data? e.g: a table in SQL Server database, SharePoint List instance, a table in Dataverse, etc.

Comment: we use a sharepiont list

Answer (score 0):

In Power Automate, create a scheduled flow that runs every day.

Declare all variables you will need later.

Assuming you store the value of the last run timestamp in a configuration SharePoint list for example, search and use the action **Get item** to get the list item where the last run time is stored in this list (you're have to create it if not existing though).

Search and use the function `utcNow()` in an expression to get the current datetime value.

Convert the previous datetime value with the action **Convert time zone** to an ISO-8601 datetime using `FormatDateTime()` function according to your timezone.

Search and use the action **Get list items** to get all the items of day from your SharePoint list, and filter the query via an OData expression according to the rule `(today's date =< last run date + frequency)`.

Search and use **Send an email V2** to send email.

Search and use the action **Update item** to update the last run time that is stored in a list item in the configuration list mentionned at the beginning.